# Wordpress site on localhost WAMP "This site can´t be reached this connection was reset ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"

Tags: apache-2.4, wordpress, localhost

I've been working on a WordPress site on localhost using WAMP. My site was slow and I saw that it would get faster if I unchecked the cgi Apache module. Now, none of my local WordPress sites load anymore, I can still access to phpmyadmin and to local sites that I´ve done from scratch just not to the WordPress ones.

I restarted all services, checked my ports, cleaned the cache, checked the `cgi_module` from Apache again, etc. I tried debugging WordPress errors but the file never appeared. Please note that I can't uninstall and reinstall WAMP since I have all my databases for other projects...

Any suggestions? My assignment is due this Sunday and I've lost three days researching :(

I'm using windows 10/ WAMPSERVER 3.2.0/ Apache 2.4.41 and WordPress 6.4.1

I don't know how to interpret Apache errors but the log says the following lines over and over:

```
AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp64\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.41\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.41'
AH00418: Parent: Created child process 10448
AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
AH00428: Parent: child process 10448 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
AH00455: Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) PHP/7.4.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
AH00456: Apache Lounge VS16 Server built: Aug  9 2019 16:46:32
```